# Select n row have highest combined value from a matrix in R

Tags: r, combinatorics

This is part of a large matrix (dimension around: 1'000-1'000'000 rows x 100 - 1'000 columns):

```
     scen_1   scen_2  scen_3    scen_4 ...
...
9  3.262275 0.000000 0.00000 0.0000000 ...
10 2.843631 0.000000 1.22636 1.0559217 ...
11 0.000000 0.000000 0.00000 0.9836209 ...
12 2.572686 0.000000 0.00000 1.1000293 ...
13 0.000000 0.000000 0.00000 0.0000000 ...
14 0.611070 1.478159 0.00000 0.0000000 ...
15 0.000000 0.000000 0.00000 0.0000000 ...
16 0.000000 0.000000 0.00000 1.0146529 ...
...
```

Now, I want to select n rows, which - after getting for each column the maximum - have the highest sum, thus row that complement each other well. E.g. I select row 9 and 10 I get the combined (max values) vector `3.262275 0.00000 1.22636 1.0559217` with a sum of `5.5445567`. Whereas if I select 14 and 16 I get  `0.611070 1.478159 0.00000 1.0146529` with a sum of `3.1038819`, thus the first option is better.

The solution for the above example for an n of 3 would be rows, 10, 14 and 9. I hope I could explain to problem well.

My approach would be to first select the row with the highest row wise sum, then literally the rows that would add the highest additional value. But I have the strong feeling that this not always gives the best solution.
Calculating all possibilities combinations is not viable due to the size of the matrix. Is a genetic algorithm a solution? Or is there a simpler approach?
Thanks.

Edit:

For easier understanding, here is an MWE:

```
# Create example matrix
mat <- matrix(c(1.562275, 0.000000, 0.00000, 0.0000000,2.843631, 0.000000, 1.22636, 1.0559217,0.000000, 0.000000, 0.00000, 0.9836209,1.572686, 0.000000, 0.00000, 1.8000293,0.000000, 0.000000, 0.00000, 0.0000000,1.611070, 1.478159, 0.00000, 0.0000000,0.000000, 0.000000, 0.00000, 0.0000000,0.000000, 0.000000, 0.00000, 1.0146529), byrow = TRUE,  ncol = 4, dimnames = list(c(9:16), c("scen_1",  "scen_2",  "scen_3", "scen_4")))

# Function to evaluate each combination of rows (this value should be maximized)
get_combined_max_value_sum <- function(choosen_rows){
  # Select rows
  sel_mat <- mat[choosen_rows,]
  
  # calculate columwise max
  max_mat <- apply(sel_mat, 2, max)
  
  # Sum the values
  return(sum(max_mat))
}

# I am looking for the function best_rows() which returns the rows, which gives the 
# maximum value (or at least a close guess) for the get_combined_max_value_sum() 
# function
best_rows <- function(n_rows){
  result <- vector()
  
  # do some magic
  
  return(result) # vector with length n_row for the "best" rows.
}

# ------------------------------------------------
# @ slamballais
# The rows with the highest rowise sum (10 & 12)
get_combined_max_value_sum(c("10","12"))

# get a lower score then row 9 and 13
get_combined_max_value_sum(c("10","14"))
```

Comment: The problem is not entirely clear. Can't you just do `rowSums` to get the sum of each row, and then just sort the rows from large to small? Then you can just select the top N rows, where N is whatever value you want.

Comment: Yeah, you're not telling us something. If you use row 9, does that mean other rows can't use the non-zero columns of row 9, or what?

Comment: Arbitrarily sized or square matrix?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added an MWE since coding sometimes is easier than explaining ;) 
@Chris: It is arbitrarily sized. And the dimesions are also not always the same.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calculating rowwise `max` ? `max_mat <- apply(sel_mat, 1, max)` . Also to clarify you are not looking for an answer which checks this for every combination of values?

Comment: What is more important to you, the value or the index of the value?

Comment: No I am looking for the column wise `max`. Imaging it as follows: The columns (scen_1, scen_2, ...) are possible scenarios of the future. The rows are different options you can choose. The values are a score of how well this option "performs" in this scenario.  I can choose n options (around 10) know, but in the future I just care about the best of those options for the scenario that happened.  

In short: I choose n rows (option) now, then I randomly choose a column. The highest value in this new matrix is my results. What rows do I have to choose in the first place to maximize my result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update (Recursive approach, sub-optimal solution)

You can define a recursive function `f` (see it within function `thomas2`), which can be any number of rows `k` (`1 <= k <= nrow(mat)`)

```
thomas2 <- function(mat, k) {
  f <- function(mat, k) {
    if (k == 1) {
      return(which.max(rowSums(mat)))
    }
    p <- f(mat, k - 1)
    q <- seq(nrow(mat))[-p]
    rmax <- apply(mat[p, , drop = FALSE], 2, max)
    c(p, q[which.max(sapply(q, function(k) sum(pmax(rmax, mat[k, ]))))])
  }
  row.names(mat)[sort(f(mat, k))]
}
```

For example

```
> thomas2(mat, 2)
[1] "10" "14"

> thomas2(mat, 3)
[1] "10" "12" "14"

> thomas2(mat, 4)
[1] "9"  "10" "12" "14"

> thomas2(mat, 5)
[1] "9"  "10" "11" "12" "14"

> thomas2(mat, 6)
[1] "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14"
```

---

## Previous answer (Brute-force approach, inefficient)

Your algorithm is a greedy one, which cannot guarantee the global maximum always. Thus, a brute-force way might a straightforward workaround to reach your goal.

Maybe you can try the following brute-force method

```
rs <- combn(nrow(mat), 3)
row.names(mat)[rs[, which.max(apply(rs, 2, function(k) sum(do.call(pmax, data.frame(t(mat[k, ]))))))]]
```

which gives

```
[1] "10" "12" "14"
```

Comment: Well, OP is asking for a solution where not all combinations are calculated, right?

Comment: @slamballais Yes, I just noticed that. I have updated my solution with a recursive one.

Comment: I think the recursive approach is a step in the right direction, but it is not finding the optimal solution for the bigger matrix (see my post). With `mat2` and `k=1`, it finds row 30, which is not part of the solution for `k=3`.  It should be possible to swap any identified rows, but I'm not entirely sure what would be the best way to do that in a recursive algorithm (never work with them.. :)  ).

Comment: I don't really exclude a brute-force method if it is an efficient one. But since, my matrices can be quite large I don't think it is feasible. I rather have a suboptimal algorithm, which can be run fast. 

The dimensions I expect are a few hundreds to a few million rows and a hundreds to a few thousand columns (I can reduce my dimension, but the results will get a bit less accurate)

Comment: @slamballais Thanks for your feedback. I would say the recursive way gives a sub-optimal solution since it starts from the row with the largest row sum and all other rows should include the selected rows in the previous iterations. I guess it would be a non-linear integer optimization problem but have no idea how to make it :P

Comment: @WitheShadow Yes, you are right. It's not a smart choice if you have large matrix. I don't know whether slamballais's solution fits you or do you have any other requirement?

Comment: I haven't had time to test it yet (will probably do it tomorrow or Wednesday), but it looks promising. At the same time I may also test your recursive function. I really appreciate the input you guys gave me :)

Comment: I am going to use your recursive function `thomas2()`. It may not always give the optimum but is has a good performance. For large matrices the brute other approaches with `combn` are not feasible. Thanks a lot for both your help.

Comment: @WitheShadow You are welcome. Glad this answer you can help you although it is sub-optimal :P

Answer (score 3):

This is not the optimal answer, but it may inspire others...

**Assumptions**

- The answer has `k` rows, where `k` is prespecified by the user.
- `k` <= `ncol(mat)`

**Answer**

Certain rows will never be part of the answer. I propose to filter out those rows before applying a brute force approach. Filter conditions so far:

- Remove rows whose sum is lower than the lowest maximum column value
- Remove rows where all values are lower than any row that contains a maximum column value

**Code**

```r
slam <- function(mat, k) {
  cm <- apply(mat, 2, max)
  rs <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) sum(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE))
  
  # remove rows whose sum is lower than the lowest column max
  matb <- subset(mat, rs > min(cm))
  
  # remove rows that have only values lower than all values of the rows containing a column max
  mrows <- matb[apply(matb, 2, which.max), ]
  any_bigger <- apply(mrows, 1, function(x) rowSums(sweep(matb, 2, x, `-`) >= 0) > 0)
  matc <- matb[apply(any_bigger, 1, all), ]
  
  # code copied + modified from @ThomasIsCoding's answer
  rs <- combn(nrow(matc), k)
  row.names(matc)[rs[, which.max(apply(rs, 2, function(z) sum(do.call(pmax, data.frame(t(matc[z, ]))))))]]
}
```

**Example + Benchmark**

```r
# bigger dataset with 100 rows and negative values too
n <- 100
n2 <- 500
set.seed(2021)
mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(n * 4), ncol = 4, dimnames = list(c(1:n), c("scen_1",  "scen_2",  "scen_3", "scen_4")))
mat3 <- matrix(rnorm(n2 * 4), ncol = 4, dimnames = list(c(1:n2), c("scen_1",  "scen_2",  "scen_3", "scen_4")))

# verification
slam(mat, 3)     # [1] "10" "12" "14"
thomas(mat)      # [1] "10" "12" "14"
slam(mat2, 3)    # [1] "25" "44" "99"
thomas(mat2)     # [1] "25" "44" "99"

# benchmark (without `thomas(mat3)`, it takes too long)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(slam(mat2, 3), thomas(mat2),
                               slam(mat3, 3), times = 1L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
# slam(mat2, 3)   249.4705   249.4705   249.4705   249.4705   249.4705   249.4705     1
#  thomas(mat2) 19557.8194 19557.8194 19557.8194 19557.8194 19557.8194 19557.8194     1
# slam(mat3, 3) 16159.9113 16159.9113 16159.9113 16159.9113 16159.9113 16159.9113     1
```

**Final thoughts**

There is another way to do this. Start out with an initial combination of the `k` rows that contain the `k` largest maximum column values. For each of those rows, calculate whether there are other rows that provide a further gain in the remaining column(s). If there is a better row, try swapping it out with the initial combination. Keep repeating this process until the best rows have been selected. I don't have time to write it right now, but if it hasn't been done by tomorrow then I'll give it a shot.